# How to make a robot following a virtual eight figure pattern without using microcontrollers?

Tags: mobile-robot

The robot should go around 2 boxes and stop at the starting point after tracing a 8 figure pattern. With micro-controllers, i guess it can be easily done using sensors or navigation algorithms. Please suggest how can be one made without them.

Comment: Hi Patz, and welcome to the Robotics Stackexchange site. Could you please add some more detail to your question. Can you draw a line on the floor for the robot to follow? What kind of robot is it? Why don't you want to use a microcontroller? Are there any other constraints?

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking but it can easily be accomplished with a track in a figure 8.  (and you get to build a cool bridge in the middle).  If you just need to travel once you can sequence the steering like in a player piano or many other mechanical automata and a spring...

Comment: You can't use microcontrollers but can you use sensors and some electronic components?

Comment: Instead of saying what you can't use, could you enumerate what you *can* use?